# how display module in popup modal window in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, popup, modal-dialog, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I have a newsletter subscription module.I want display it in popup window automatically(when user view a page,without any click).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here at Stackoverflow, we don't do your work for you, we expect you to have atleast tried something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modal window. You can make a new custom html module and load javascript to do it.

This is just one solution and probably not the best.